# valgrind error Invalid read of size 8

Tags: c, memory-leaks, malloc, valgrind

So I have valgrind complaining with this error in this function:

```
int getMembersNum(Party party){
    assert(party != NULL);
    int i = 0;
    while (party->members[i] != NULL && i < party->maxMembersNum) <-- HERE
            i++;
    return i;
```

}

Party is a pointer to a struct and `party->members` is of type `char**`. When initialized with `malloc` all of `party->members` cells are set to `NULL`.

What am I missing?

Comment: valgrind thinks that one of you members pointers is not initialized. maybe you have an out by one error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to test before you use.

```
while (party->members[i] != NULL && i < party->maxMembersNum)
```

should be

```
while (i < party->maxMembersNum && party->members[i] != NULL)
```

Comment: That solved 14 out of 17 errors. Now to solve the other 3 (who have the same problem in a different function). Thank you.